# Dropdown-large - Bootstrap

Tags: dropdown

im trying to do a big dropdown menu but when i click on a main dropdown-toggle TEXT it only highlight but nothing happen... - check the picture

```html
<li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TEXT</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
        <li class="col-sm-3">
         <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Glyphicons</li>
            <li><a href="#">Available glyphs</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">How to use</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Headers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[Only Highlight but do not show dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A74Cc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be causing the problem : `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TEXT</a>` You don't want your toggle button to be a direct link, instead use the intended **Bootstrap** class

Check this JSFiddle, I think this is what you are trying to do : [Answer](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/278/)

If this answer solves your problem, please do accept it.